# Can EC2 instances dynamically add RAM while running?

Tags: amazon-ec2, memory

This would help contribute to 0 downtime for me if possible. As far as I know it is *not* possible, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: No. The closest thing is probably Auto-Scaling http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/

Comment: @TheInternet your question was likely downvoted because it showed very little input on your part. Have a read through the following http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Comment: Thanks for censoring me @Drew Khoury. This type of question isn't a "what did you try?" type of question but a "yes/no" type. Take a look at "How can I get people to fully read my question" http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2177/how-can-i-get-people-to-fully-read-my-question

Comment: It sounds like your real problem/question is around achieving zero (or close to) down-time which you can certainly do with AWS and EC2s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible in EC2.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to stop your EC2 and change the instance type to add more RAM so **no it can't be done dynamically**, or on-the-fly.

## Alternatives

You're interested in no downtime so you should take a look into a number of features:

- Elastic Load Balancing (ELB)
- Elastic Network Interface (ENI)

You can create an ELB and attach an EC2 to it. Next you could clone your EC2, change it's instance type, and bring the clone into the load balancer. Finally you terminate the old EC2 out, completing the 'zero downtime' upgrade.

You could attach an ENI to your EC2. Create a clone, change instance type, attach ENI to the new EC2. Finally, terminate the old EC2.

Comment: It's interesting that Virtualbox supports Hot Add Ram and Hot Plug CPU. Why not a cloud provider?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Consider that the instance might be running on a physical hypervisor that has no available RAM or additional CPUs. They could live-migrate the VM to another physical host, but I don't believe that AWS does this at all (or "instance retirement" for EC2s without ephemeral storage would not be a thing). I don't think it makes sense for AWS to offer hot-adding resources if they can't guarantee that it will always be possible.

Comment: Stopping, 'adding more ram' by changing instance type and starting again introduced me to a hell of errors and troubleshooting, couldnt ssh anymore, status checks failed for no clear reason etc. This seems like a bug and not much info about it. I ended up starting from scratch